# How do I find if a datetime in one list falls in between dates in another list in a quick manner (python)?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have lists that look like this that has a lot of tickers and values and dates:

```
values = [['NKE', 1, 2, datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 20)], ['AAPL', 1, 2, datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1)],['AAPL', 3, 4, datetime.datetime(2016,4,2)]...]

releasedates = [['AAPL', Q3, 2015, datetime.datetime(2015, 10,5)], ['AAPL', Q4,2015, datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 5)], ['AAPL', Q1, 2016, datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 9)]
```

releasedates refers to the end of quarters for that company.  I want to have a list that has all the information in values in each line, but also shows what quarter the information would be a part of.  So for the above information the end result would look like this:

```
values_releasedates = [...['AAPL',1,2, Q4, 2015], ['AAPL', 3,4, Q1, 2016]...]
```

(I only show AAPL here, other companies like NKE from values would be there as well with their own entries)

This code here works:

```
values_releasedates = [[ticker, a, b, quarter, year] for ticker, a, b, date in values for [ticker_1, quarter_1, year_1, date_1], [ticker_2, quarter_2, year_2, date_2] in zip(releasedates, releasedates[1:]) if date_1 < date < date_2 and ticker == ticker_1]
```

but takes really long.  I was thinking maybe I could create some sort of dictionary that would cut time somehow so that if in values a NKE entry pops up it only will look at NKE releasedates.  But I'm such a novice I don't know where to start.

Comment: You're trying to do way too much in a single list comprehension and because of this, there are logical errors & inefficiencies in your method: This will populate between ticker AAPLQ1/Q2 all ticker dates which fall between it's range, which I'm fairly certain is not your intent.

Comment: @TemporalWolf  If what you're saying is that I want all entries from values with AAPL tickers to be appended between the correct two filing dates, I do want that to happen.  There could be potentially a lot per quarter.  Any thoughts on how to make this more efficient?  (I updated my code to have it specify where ticker == ticker_1)

Comment: your current code is `O(n*m)`, when an optimized version would be `O(n+m)` (assuming values is already sorted by date). You need to break up the list comprehension, like I said. Break both lists into lists by ticker. then, for each ticker, build the quarterly range once for that ticker, and then iterate through both lists until you reach the end of `values_by_ticker[ticker]`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get you started in the right direction:

Break both lists by ticker:

```
# Example of values
values_by_ticker = {}
for value in values:
    try:
        values_by_ticker[value[0]].append(value)
    except KeyError:
        values_by_ticker[value[0]] = [value]
```

Then, iterate through each value in values_by_ticker, figuring out when it belongs:

```
result = []
for ticker in values_by_ticker:
    release_index = 0
    for value in ticker:
        while True:
            daterange = (rel_by_ticker[release_index], 
                         rel_by_ticker[release_index + 1])
            if is_in_range(value[3], daterange): # Exercise left for the reader
                result.append([value[0], 
                               value[1], 
                               value[2], 
                               rel_by_ticker[release_index][1], 
                               rel_by_ticker[release_index][1]])
                break
            else:
                release_index += 1
```

This is `O(n+m)`, assumes both lists are sorted and won't handle errors (such as when you get to the last quarter for any particular ticker), but it should point you in the right direction.

I also haven't run the second part, so there may be errors, but the logic should be sound.